# Is $\{\frac{1}{n}\ \mid n\in \mathbb N\}=\{x\in \mathbb R \mid 0<x\le 1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Is $\{\frac{1}{n}\ \mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ the same as $\{x\in \mathbb R \mid 0<x\le 1\}$?

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? I am asking a legitimate question.

Comment: Well, there are the usual issues: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? It's also really unclear exactly where the issue in your understanding is - these sets are *very* fundamentally different, and it's not obvious what the basis of the question is.

Comment: Not even close.

Comment: You didn't offer any indication on what you did to figure it out on your own.  Did you even *try* to look at a real number.  What about 2/3?  Is 2/3 = 1/n?  What about .... *ANY* irrational number.  Is there any irrational 1/n?  Did it not occur to you that 1, 1/2, 1/4 doesn't include *any* number between 1 and 1/2? 1/2 and 1/4, etc.?

Comment: @fleablood No, it did not occur to me, hence why I asked the question here.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but why *didn't* it occur to you.  {1/n} is a very clear and distinct and we'll defined set on which you can examine any element.  As is (0,1].  Why didn't it occur to you to try to find an element in one that wouldn't be in the other?  Simply noticing 2/3 should have made the answer obvious.

Answer (score 2):

A simple counter-example:

> $\color{red}{\frac{14}{17} \in \{x\in \mathbb R \mid 0<x\le 1\}}$

but

> $\color{blue}{\frac{14}{17} \not \in \{\frac{1}{n}\ \mid n\in \mathbb N\}}$

since there exists no such $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that can produce such a number.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not.

For example, consider $x=\frac23$. $x\in\mathbb R$ and $0<x\le1$

If $\frac1n=\frac23$, we get $n=\frac32 \notin \mathbb N$

This implies $x\in\{x\in\mathbb R | 0<x\le1\}$ but $x\notin\{\frac1n |n\in\mathbb N\}$

Answer (score 0):

No.  {1/n} does not contain any irrational number.  It does not contain any a/b in lowest terms a>1.  It does not contain any x such that 1/2  x > 1/(n+1). Etc.  {1/n} is countable while (0,1] is not.

The are not remotely the same.